# Drawing a board for the board game GO (HTML canvas)

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

I am working on a *GO* game in JavaScript and drawing the board is important to be efficient because it gets ran multiple times a second. As when the user moves their mouse, it will simulate where their game piece is going to go, so the board must rebuild lots of times.

It looks ok at the moment, a bit long and it draws the numbers and letters on the outside even though that's constant, if you get what I mean. So that bit could be done better so it only writes that text once and then just resets the middle bit. I'm also trying to make it completely scalable, and I think I have done a good job so far.

If you want to try out the board of jsFiddle, I also included the functions to simulate dropping a game piece, if you want to comment on that. But this post was mainly just for drawing the board. For this code, I'll just put the drawing of the grid.

[jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1opfqyd5/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("game-canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var boardSize = 13;
var border = canvas.width / 10;
var boardWidth = canvas.width - (border * 2);
var boardHeight = canvas.height - (border * 2);

var cellWidth = boardWidth / (boardSize - 1);
var cellHeight = boardHeight / (boardSize - 1);


function drawGrid()
{   
    var backgroundColor = '#F5DEB3';
    var gridColor = '#8B4513';

    context.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.fillStyle = gridColor;

    for (var i = 0; i < boardSize - 1; i++) //Draws the board
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < boardSize - 1; j++)
        {
            context.fillRect(i * cellWidth + border, j * cellHeight + border, cellWidth - 1, cellHeight - 1);
        }
    }

    var quater = Math.floor((boardSize - 1) / 4);
    var markerSize = 8;
    var markerMargin = (markerSize / 2) + 0.5;

    context.fillStyle = backgroundColor;

    if (!!(boardSize % 2)) //If its an odd number eg (13 x 13), draw the middle marker
    {
        context.fillRect((((boardSize - 1) / 2) * cellWidth) + border - markerMargin, (((boardSize - 1) / 2) * cellWidth) + border - markerMargin, markerSize, markerSize);
    }
    //Draw the other 4 markers
    context.fillRect((quater * cellWidth) + border - markerMargin, (quater * cellWidth) + border - markerMargin, markerSize, markerSize);
    context.fillRect((((boardSize - 1) - quater) * cellWidth) + border - markerMargin, (quater * cellWidth) + border - markerMargin, markerSize, markerSize);

    context.fillRect((((boardSize - 1) - quater) * cellWidth) + border - markerMargin, (((boardSize - 1) - quater) * cellWidth) + border - markerMargin, markerSize, markerSize);
    context.fillRect((quater * cellWidth) + border - markerMargin, (((boardSize - 1) - quater) * cellWidth) + border - markerMargin, markerSize, markerSize);

    var size = canvas.width / 40;
    var textSpacing = 10;
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.font = size + "px Arial";

    //draw the numbers and letters
    for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
    {
        context.fillText((i + 1), textSpacing, ((canvas.height - border) - (i * cellHeight)) + (size / 3));
        context.fillText((i + 1), canvas.width - (size + textSpacing), ((canvas.height - border) - (i * cellHeight)) + (size / 3)); 

        context.fillText((String.fromCharCode(97 + i)), (border + (i * cellHeight) + (size / 3)) - (size / 1.5), textSpacing + size);       
        context.fillText((String.fromCharCode(97 + i)), (border + (i * cellHeight) + (size / 3)) - (size / 1.5), canvas.height - (textSpacing * 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Was there some reason why you didn't post this question under your [main account](/users/140137/rachel-dockter)?

Comment: Only performance boost I can think of is either only redrawing 8 cells when you move your mouse and the circle changes place or make another layer for that so you don´t need to redraw board